# how to dot product two vectors with different planes?

Tags: analytic-geometry

how to dot product two vectors with different planes?

I have vectors $A$,$B$ and $C$, vectors $A$ and $B$ is on $xy$ plane while vector $C$ is on $xz$ plane. I need to find the dot product of $A.C$ how should I do that? my book says that dot product of two vectors can be expressed in terms of their rectangular components. vector $B$ lies in $y$-axis. vector $A$ makes $60$ degrees to $B$, vector $C$ makes $37$ degrees to $x$-axis. $A=10$, $B=8$ and $C=5$.

please help me to solve this problem

Comment: Dot product in Cartesian/rectangular coordinates: $(a_1,a_2,a_3)\cdot(b_1,b_2,b_3)=a_1b_1+a_2b_2+a_3b_3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

B lies in y- axis , then A makes 30 degrees with x-axis, so that:
$$A=10\cos30\, i+10\sin30\,j\qquad A=5\sqrt3\,i+5\,j$$
$$C=5\cos37\,i+5\sin37\,k\quad =4\,i+3\,k$$
$$A.C=20\sqrt3$$

Comment: please explain why A=10cos30i + 10sin30j and C=5cos37i + 5sin37k

Comment: A makes 60 degrees with B, and B lies in y-axis, then the angle between A and the x-axis is $90-60=30$, C lies in the xz plane so it has x component (i) and z-component (k).

Comment: why does C has no y-component? is it because it only lies to x-z plane?

Comment: yes, nothing else.

Comment: how about if the vector C lies in x-y-z plane? how do i find the components of C?

Comment: See this http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCoordinates.html

Comment: thank you sir for your help and the link.. i appreciate the link you gave even it is spherical coordinate system. i only know rectangular coordinate system. thank you again